# Android Studio Gradle on Server

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have installed Android Studio and gradle as required but while creating a new project I get this error

```
com.intellij.openapi.options.ConfigurationException: Failed to import new Gradle project: Could not fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'.
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/1.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read below process output to find out more:
-----------------------
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:397)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.EffectiveClassPath.findAvailableClasspathFiles(EffectiveClassPath.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.EffectiveClassPath.<init>(EffectiveClassPath.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.classpath.DefaultModuleRegistry.<init>(DefaultModuleRegistry.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon.main(GradleDaemon.java:22)
```

After lots of searching I think it is due to the fact that the .gradle folder is on a common server. "\ServerName\UserProfiles\naveen\.gradle" and AndroidStudio is not able to access it.
I also tried to change the path in Configure->Settings->gradle->ServiceDirectoryPath but it wont let me change that.
None of the problems on SO related to Android studio have any relation to what I have here.

So is there some way to change the path or maybe edit some file in AndroidStudio from which I can change Gradle Path and make it static. 
I don't want to unlink my computer from server or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

go to C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\plugins\gradle\lib

and delete this files slf4j-api and slf4j-log4j12

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the gradle daemon with user home directory being a network location.  Try setting a Windows environment variable GRADLE_USER_HOME to a local directory.

http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2010/09/gradle-goodness-changing-gradle-user.html

Also, on windows 7, the user home envrionment variable might be set to a UNC path. Try adding -Duser.home=c:\some\path

[Gradle Integration for Eclipse daemon startup failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19577789/gradle-integration-for-eclipse-daemon-startup-failure)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Gradle Wrapper](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html) that doesn't relay on environment variables.  If you execute `gradle init` on a project's root it will apply the appropriate wrapper files (along with the empty .gradle files if they don't exist).

This [**Android & Gradle Tutorial**](http://blog.iteedee.com/2014/01/android-gradle-tutorial/) goes into great detail about using the platform.